# How to create string variables for Threads and delete them using flag

Tags: python, arrays, regex, multithreading, dictionary

As I told in title, I want to create `string variables` for `Threads` using `input`. And delete them using `flag`.

I need to explain this question step by step.

1. Let's say, I'm getting `input` from user. This `input` by the user will be the name of the `Thread variable`.
2. Let the `input` be equal to `love` and `like`. In this case, there will be 2 Threads variable's and Threads created. And their names will be `love` and `like`.
3. To create a `Thread`, such a code must be given.

***The code:***

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import re

# Using while loop. Because I want to create multiple Threads by doing this.

# Dicts
dicts = {}
flags = {}

while True:

    # Input
    threadName = input('Thread name please? ')

    # To delete a Thread
    if 'delete' in threadName:
        delThread = re.search(r'delete (.*)', threadName)
        if delThread:
            delThread = list(map(str, delThread.groups()))
            delThread = ''.join(delThread)
            print('DELETING:', delThread)
            flags[delThread] = True
            print('DICT NOW:', flags)
    else:
        # Target function for every Thread. Print a message every 3 secs.
        def targetfunc(tname):
            while True:
                if flags[tname] in flags and flags[tname] == True:
                    break
                print(f"I'm {tname} Thread.")
                time.sleep(3)

        # Create Threads. 'dicts[threadName]' will be whatever the user enters input.
        # Should be string variable.
        # 'threadName' is equal to input too.
 
        dicts[threadName] = Thread(target = targetfunc, args = [threadName])
        dicts[threadName].start()
        flags[threadName] = False
        print(dicts)
        print(flags)
```

I'm using 2 dicts. The `dicts` for creating `Threads` and the other one for deleting them using `flag`.

**To create**, just type what do you want to call to Thread.

**To delete**, type `delete (thread name)`.

***The input from user:***

```
Thread name please? love
{'love': <Thread(Thread-1, stopped 47635696609024)>}
{'love': False}
Thread name please? like
{'love': <Thread(Thread-1, stopped 47635696609024)>, 'like': <Thread(Thread-2, stopped 47635696609024)>}
{'love': False, 'like': False}
Thread name please? delete love
DELETING: love
DICT NOW: {'love': True, 'like': False}
```

This code throws `KeyError` for each Thread when I try to delete. Here is the full error.

***The error:***

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./prog.py", line 27, in targetfunc
KeyError: 'love'

Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./prog.py", line 27, in targetfunc
KeyError: 'like'
```

That's the program. How to fix this problem?

***What I want to achieve is:***

When I type a *name*, that *name* must create a new `Thread` with that *name*. But when I type `delete (thread name)` this should stop `(thread name) Thread`.

I hope I could explain it well. Hope you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are checking the dictionary entry instead of checking if that key exists.

Change this line:

```
if flags[tname] in flags and flags[tname] == True:
```

To this:

```
if tname in flags and flags[tname] == True:
```

With this change, the code runs correctly.